# maven assembly plugin filters some files, but not others

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project being built on Linux but which needs scripts to be run on windows. So I generate batch files for starting the server under windows. These need to refer to a versioned jar. I also tag the README file with a `${project.version}` the version so the uer can easily see about which version the file pertains to .

So I create an assembly descriptor :

```
...
<files>
    <file>
        <source>README</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>start-server.cmd</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
        <lineEnding>dos</lineEnding>
    </file>
</files>
...
```

In the **README** file is the line

```
     README ${project.version}
```

and in **start-server.cmd** I have

```
     VERSION = ${project.version}
```

and after `mvn assembly:assembly` and unzipping the generated artifact

I find in README :

```
     README 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

and in the start-server.cmd

```
     VERSION = ${project.version}
```

I am completely at a loss why it is replaced in one file and not in the other.

Comment: very odd... Maven has some extensions which are excluded by default such as .jpg and .png, but .cmd isn't one of them. Is it something to do with the lineEnding part? What if you try putting the ${..} in different parts of the line, i.e. not right at the end?

Comment: different positions do not help. Before this version it was in the middle of a classpath definition on a java commandline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you are hitting the issue discussed in this [forum](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Assembly-filtering-syntax-properties-not-filtered-td3288110.html), which is to do with @ symbol in the `start-server.cmd` and `maven resource plugin`?

Comment: In case the forum disappears, the bug was http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-104